# How to filter Google Sheets by multiple contains using AND

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I've searched for something similar but couldn't quite duplicate based on some other posts.

Column `F` has data on which websites you have a login with.

Let's say

`F2 = Amazon, Facebook, Google, Twitter`

`F3 = Amazon, Google, Twitter`

`F4 = Amazon, Netflix, HBO`

I want to filter the column to show all records that contain BOTH Amazon AND Twitter. So, the filtered results should show only `F2` and `F3`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. For simplicity's sake, I recommend this:

`=FILTER(F2:F,REGEXMATCH(F2:F,"Amazon"),REGEXMATCH(F2:F,"Twitter"))`

It should be easy to understand and add to as needed.

Comment: How would I do this in the Filter by condition custom formula?

Comment: Applied to F2:F, use this: =REGEXMATCH(F2:F,"Amazon")*REGEXMATCH(F2:F,"Twitter")

Comment: Small error there. You only need this: =REGEXMATCH(F2,"Amazon")*REGEXMATCH(F2,"Twitter")

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on your comment:**

Use this as a custom filter formula:

`=REGEXMATCH(F2,"(?i)Amazon.*Twitter|Twitter.*Amazon")`

[image]

**As a google sheets formula:**

`=FILTER(F2:F,REGEXMATCH(F2:F,"(?i)Amazon.*Twitter|Twitter.*Amazon"))`

[image: regex]

Comment: How would I do this in the Filter by condition custom formula?

Comment: @Craig see my updated answer.